# useappcompat v7 actionbar on api 8 theme issue

Tags: android

Is it possible to use normal holo theme when using appcompat.v7.actionbar instead of themes.appcompat.light? Because when I do everything just looks poor quality resource or graphics wise. The actionbar seems quite messy as well after I used appcompat theme. Thank you

Comment: "do everything"? What are you doing? Show code.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you want to use a lib project [HoloEverywhere](https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere)